# Waterproof Pan control/bearing/mechanism

Tags: bearings, servo, waterproofing

Please bear with me - I'm not an engineer, I'm a software developer so lack the language / knowledge to describe what I want precisely.

I'm controlling a servo to rotate /pan a platform to hold a camera (think pan/tilt). This is fine.

However, I'd like to house the servo/electronics in a waterproof box, and have a platform on top of the box that Pans.

How can I transfer the rotation through a waterproof enclosure? Is there such a thing as a waterproof bearing, that the servo can rotate one side within the enclosure, and have the rotation exposed on the outside, so I can attach the Panning platform to it?

Does such a thing exist? If so, what is it called?

If not, surely this is a problems that has already been solved
 Can anyone direct me to a solution for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Look for the cameras in the streets or on motorways...

Comment: I understand how the mechanism works, I need a name for it so I can research it. Something something bulkhead transfer something maybe?

Comment: Surely just an O ring around the rotating shaft would solve this? It’s not really a device that solves the problem - there would simply be a groove in the housing that the O ring sits in before the shaft is posted through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a "shaft gland" / "gland seal" used in boats (and for my application, radio controlled boats" to solve the problem.